# Eliminate multiple pages in lists?

Tags: list, list-view

We have gone beyond the 30 line limit in a SharePoint list and would like to either reorder the list to start with the last item or hide the first page of entries. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am reading your post incorrectly, this should work:

1) Go to the library/list settings

2) Click the view you would like to edit at the bottom of the page

3) Navigate down to the **Sort** section

4) Select the primary and secondary columns you wish to sort by

5) Choose ascending or descending

6) Click OK

[image: View Settings]

FYI - On the same page as the **Sort** section, the **Item Limit** section will let you specify the maximum number of items that can be displayed in your list views. Also, the **Filter** section will let you select conditions for displaying lines.

Hope that helps,

Nick

Comment: Nick that does help. I'm thinking about this a little differently based on your response. Is there a way for me to archive or hide completed items in the list?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you, Lena. You can use the **Filter** section to hide items with a specific value. For example, if you have a column containing a value that indicates which items have been completed (something like "Approved" or "Completed"), you can select the _Show items only when the following is true_ option. From the drop-down menu below, choose the column name and specify the flag value. It would be something like: **Status** _is equal to_ "Approved".